# Multiline error message reporting in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell function which reports a long error message. Although I can write this message in one line, I want to break it into two or more e.g.

```
foo a b | a > b = a
        | a == b = b
        | otherwise = error "Blah blah blah blah in this line and 
                      some more blah in this line also."
```

GHCi does not compile it. Any suggestion? A casual googleing did not produce any answer.

Comment: If you want the message to be split into two lines when the error is thrown, not just in the source code, then Use `\n` within the string to insert a newline character.

Comment: perhaps a better title for the question would be "multiline string literals in Haskell?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just concatenate the strings:

```
foo a b | a > b = a
        | a == b = b
        | otherwise = error ("Blah blah blah blah in this line and"
                      ++ " some more blah in this line also.")
```

this works for me

Comment: Ah, I was trying this but forgot the bracket. Thanks!

Comment: The annoying thing is that `error "string 1" ++ "string 2"` does compile, even though it's totally wrong. I wonder if there are tools like HLint that can detect that kind of mistake.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ghc's multi-line string syntax for this:

```
foo a b | a > b = a
        | a == b = b
        | otherwise = error "Blah blah blah blah in this line and \
                            \some more blah in this line also."
```

For errors it doesn't matter much, but in other contexts it can be more efficient than concatenating strings.

Comment: Two points: First, AFAIK ghc will turn `"abc" ++ "def"` automatically into `"abcdef"` if compiled with `-O1` or higher and second, this syntax **does not** inserts newlines for you. It just allows you to split the string over multiple lines.

Comment: It doesn't look like he was claiming it inserted newlines.  Good point about the optimization though, not that I count on SO askers to use `-O n`, even when benchmarking!

Comment: IMO the question isn't entirely clear on whether it's about inserting newlines into literals, writing a string literal on multiple lines, or  both, although I read it as writing a string literal on multiple lines.  Thankfully the issues are orthogonal.